# Git ssh proxy password in VS 2019

Tags: git, azure, ssh, proxy, visual-studio-2019

I am having trouble acessing a git repo via ssh because of the companies firewall in a windows 8 machine.

I managed to set up a proxy in ~/.ssh/config as follows :

`ProxyCommand C:/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe -H <proxy.address> %h %p`

This  proxy already allows me to clone the repository via comand line sucessfuly, upon runing

`git clone <azure.ssh.address>`

I am prompted for the proxy password and after providing it the clone works like a charm.

However in Visual Studio 2019 team explorer when cloning via ssh i receive the following error:

> Git failed with a fatal error.
>   FATAL: Cannot decide password for proxy authentication.ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Without ever prompting for the proxy password.

Is there a way to hard code the proxy password in ssh's config file so i am not require to input it and visual studio can clone as well, Or some other workaround ?

P.S: Machine is a windows 8 machine, and the repo is a azure devops git repo

Comment: I do not think `connect.exe` has support for authentication. Look into using another tunneling tool - such as [`corkscrew`](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew), seems avilable over [homebrew](https://github.com/fasterthanlime/homebrew-mingw/blob/master/Library/Formula/corkscrew.rb)

Comment: @fredrik i had come across references to corkscrew, but how would i go about installing/using this in a windows machine ?  seems to only be available on linux and mac.

Comment: A google search for `corkscrew windows` yielded [this](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/corkscrew.html). If you can't find it for your environment you'll have to compile it on your own.